# What is the color code of the border

Tags: swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am trying to modify this netbeans border color as it is bright on a dark background. Does anybody know the color key or the actual RGB values for this ?

Comment: No, but I'd: **1.** do a print screen **2.** use an image editor (e.g. [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)) to [get the RGB value of a pixel](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-color-picker.html)

Comment: Didn't know GIMP did this. Thanks for the tip. Do you want to reply in an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: the existing answers are good enough; pick whichever of them you find best

Comment: Looks like the folks here are very stuck up, I will delete the question.

Comment: No, dont delete pls. Everyone who has spent time to answer here will hate you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the color details:

[image: Screenshot]

Or you use the [ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) software.
I recommend this if you do this more often.

[image: ColorPic Screenshot]

Comment: It would be a better idea to use our dedicated imgur server for image uploads instead - those are much more well-guarded against link rot.

Answer (score 3):

Why couldn't you open this image with an image editing tool and use the dropper?

RGB: 185 / 207 / 228

Comment: Because I had no clue Gimp had such a feature. Thanks anyway.